# Google map zoom buttons not loading due to content security policy: "Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml..."

Tags: google-maps

My site with a google maps javascript API object isn't loading a lot of images.

Chrome dev tools dropped this:

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' <URL> <URL> <URL> <URL>".

userone:1 Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%20018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com".
```

This message was repeated over and over for many images on the page.

Comment: what soultion worked for you? i am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding `data:image/svg+xml` to my Content Security Policy (CSP):

```
'img-src': ["'self'",
  ...
  'data:',
  ...
]
```

Note that `data:` is insecure:

> An attacker can also inject arbitrary `data:` URIs.  Use this sparingly and definitely not for scripts.

Source: [MDN: Content Security Policy: img-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src#Sources)

Comment: Adding data:image/svg+xml to the CSP is actually invalid. Source: [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src)

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your case possible, you can also solve this problem the other way around by removing the default Google map UI or removing all controls that use images.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    // remove all controls
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    // or just the ones that need images
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultUI

In this case:

- zoom is still possible with double right / left click, fingers
- Street View / fullscreen [/ other navigation] isn't used

But if you really do want all the default functionality and you do not want to change your CSP, you can add custom controls that would use your own images. More info can also be found in the link above. I personally took this approach, i'm always better safe than sorry.